# I want to apply in this company because they provide international mobility. How should i write it?

Tags: cover-letter, international

I'm a french student in industrial engineering, working in apprenticeship and I would like to go abroad for my first job. I heard, from another's company employee, they are searching for an industrial engineer for a 2 years mission in USA. However, I can't find this post on their website. I would like to submit a spontaneous application, but how should I write, in my cover letter, I want to apply *only if a can go abroad* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it.

Mention that you heard from another employee about this job. There is nothing wrong with that.

And if the heading of your cover letter contains something like:

> *Application for industrial engineer for 2 years mission in USA*

it is aboundently clear that you only want this job if you can go abroad.

Comment: Agreed. A lot of companies have a rather weird HR department when it comes to recruiting people. They are not always aware what job ads they have on other sites. However, applying for a company is never bad. I've applied to MANY companies that had no job offers and most of them were interested in me. Meaning I had a royal choice in where I wanted to work.